# What is the fastest or easiest way to select a bunch of cells in a column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, shortcuts

Excel Version: 2013 (32-bit)
OS: Windows 7 (32-bit)

Looking preferably for a non-vba option.

I have to select a range of cells in a particular column. I use the CTRL + SHIFT + DOWN ARROW options. But lot of these cells are blanks, which means holding on to the buttons for a long time (data runs into excess of 5000 rows).

Is there a easier or faster method to select such kind of data. I know the trick of typing in the last cell address in the range and enter while holding down the shift key, but I am looking for a different solution, as in this one i first have to find the last cell in the range, then type it, then hold all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Select the first cell you wish to select, hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, enter the last of the cells you want to select, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click "OK"

This should select all of the intended cells.

Comment: The problem is selecting the last cell

Comment: Since i cannot comment on your acutal question, i must do it here-  The final paragraph in your Question doesnt make very much sense. If you mean select a column with gaps in between (Data in A1, blank in A2, data in A3,  then i will edit my answer to fit that.

Comment: do you possibly mean start from the last cell?

Comment: And what do you mean by "The problem is selecting the last cell"? Do you mean that you are trying to select the last cell in a sheet?

Comment: I think what he means to say is that he does not know the last of the cells he wants to select in advance.

Comment: Well, AFAIK, there is no way to select a cell without knowing the location/coordinates of said cell. The question is structured badly, so i do not know exactly what he means

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is:

If first row is 1, its easy:
Click on the column identifier (the button with the column letter on it. I don't know the proper name), then press and hold Shift+Ctrl and press Up arrow.

Or

1. Go to 1st cell of the column you wish to select.
2. Shift+Ctrl+End - This will select all rows but some extra columns
   (all used columns)
3. Keeping Shift pressed adjust column selection.

Unless you have a lot of columns and are trying to select one in the middle this will work fast.